# Understanding Galera Status wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg

Tags: mariadb, galera

Does `wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg` really represent the average size of the `wsrep_local_recv_queue`?

For the MariaDB version below I have problems to understand the status value of it, because the `wsrep_local_recv_queue` is `0` all the time, but `wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg` is sometimes very high (above 500), even though the node has been restarted 600 seconds ago and 580 of those 600 seconds the queue size is 0 and only 10-15 seconds after starting the mysql node the receive queue can be as high as 10000, but is being saved away fastly.

The `wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg` value is even also only decreasing in fractions when checking the value regularly.

So please enlighten me, what this value actually represents if not the average receive queue size for the node's uptime.

```
~ $ dpkg -l | grep mariadb
ii  libmariadbclient18                5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         amd64        MariaDB database client library
ii  mariadb-client-5.5                5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         amd64        MariaDB database client binaries
ii  mariadb-client-core-5.5           5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         amd64        MariaDB database core client binaries
ii  mariadb-common                    5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         all          MariaDB database common files (e.g. /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.cnf)
ii  mariadb-galera-server             5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         all          MariaDB database server with Galera cluster (metapackage depending on the latest version)
ii  mariadb-galera-server-5.5         5.5.45+maria-1~wheezy         amd64        MariaDB database server with Galera cluster binaries
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MariaDB KB: Galera Cluster Status Variables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg):

> **Description:** Average length of the receive queue since the most recent
>   status query. If this value is noticeably larger than zero, the node
>   is likely to be overloaded, and cannot apply the writesets as quickly
>   as they arrive, resulting in replication throttling.

So it not the average receive queue size for the node's uptime, but since the last time you queried this status.

Comment: This seems incorrect in documentation as I can confirm, for the past 2 years, this value is huge on a node after first joining (using backup method) of a 100GB DB, and slowly decreasing over time. FWIW, I run show status like 'wsrep%' every seconds or so for monitoring and was looking for a way to reset at run time. It's much lower after an IST.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation in the other answer is likely wrong or using inaccurate wording.

Here is appropriate documentation:
https://mariadb.com/docs/server/ref/mdb/status-variables/wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg/

**This status variable provides the average number of entries found in the local received queue since the node started or since the last FLUSH STATUS statement.**

I was looking for a way to reset those values and stumbled on this post and figured out a FLUSH STATUS would do it.

FWIW Once the flush command is issued, all nodes resets wsrep status information.